# Why should we use display table instead of block in order to clearfix?

Tags: css

I see many people are using the display table to clearfix as following:

```
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

However, I tried to use `display:block` instead of `display:table`. It worked perfectly. I'm just curious if there are any secrets behind the display table?

Comment: not sure.. I always used `display: block`. lets see.. btw, where you have seen this?

Comment: @Mr_Green, It's recommended in [CSS-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/).